# How do I wire a remote ceiling fan with two switches?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, remote-control

We would like set up our remote to control the fan and the light switch to control the light. There was another fan installed but not with remote but had a light. The dual light switch was set up that one controlled the light and the other controlled the fan.

- I have two black, two white and two bare wires coming from the
  ceiling
- The remote has unit has a black, gray, blue, and yellow wire
  on it
- No Red wire is coming from the ceiling which is confusing as    most
  of the posts include instructions with a red wire

Comment: What do the directions for the remote say?  Is there a diagram on the remote unit?

Comment: What make and model is your fan and remote? Is changing the remote out for a different remote in the cards?